# codemirror 6 detect deleted line with breakpoint to move the breakpoint to previous line

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-6

I follow [this Gutters Example](https://codemirror.net/examples/gutter/) for toggle breakpoints. I want to move the breakpoint to `line - 1` if the line with the breakpoint marker is deleted or empty.
The problem is I don't know how to detect if the line has been deleted or not, the set was updated with `set.map(transaction.changes)`. does anyone know the solutions?